# SSRS passing multiple string parameter to another report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have read some other posts about this problem, but couldn't get it to work unfortunately.

I have 2 SSRS reports. The first report take a multiple string parameters, runs a select query, and present some rows. Then I have a "Go to Report" Action that pass the values to a sub report and run an update query to update the rows.

When passing the multiple value parameter to another report I used
=join(Parameters!ponum.Value,",") but the sub report only recognize the parameter as 1 value. The parameter on the sub report has set to allow multiple value already.

The type of values I want to pass is like 'a-01', 'b-02', 'd01-293'. However, when passed to another report the parameter becomes a-01, b-02, d01-293

I tried to pass with = "'" + join(Parameters!ponum.Value,"','") + "'" but still fails.

Is there any other ways I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting to the seconds report as a subreport or via a URL?

Comment: I am getting to the subreport via an action that says "Go to report"

Comment: does the sub report run ok with multiple parameters on it's own? I.E. run the sub report with the same multiple parameters - does it display ok?

Comment: further to my comment.. what is the difference in passing 'a-01', 'b-02', 'd01-293' as opposed to a-01, b-02, d01-293 ? isn't the second one a lot tidier to work with?

Comment: The subreport does okay with parameter on its own. If I enter values on the sub reports it correctly works with the query such as

**_select * from po where my_param in ('a-01', 'b-02', 'c-03')_**

On the other hand, the database wouldn't query anything if query is 

**_select * from po where my_param in (a-01, b-02, d01-293)_**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subreport's parameter is multi-value like your main report parameter then in the subreport properties all you do is set the parameter value to your main report's parameter.

So if we have `MainReport` with a parameter called `PoNum` and it is multi-value. Then we have `mySubReport` with a parameter of `subPONums` for example then in the subreport placeholder in the main report, set the parameter value to `[@PoNum]`

[image]

The entire parameter object will be passed to the subreport.