# Passing multiple string parameters to a another report via "Go to report" Action

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I had similar question for sub report and was answered:
[SSRS passing multiple string parameter to another report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266696/ssrs-passing-multiple-string-parameter-to-another-report)

However this time I would like to pass my parameters to a different report instead of a sub report.

For the first report, my ponum parameter consist of string like 'a-01', 'b-02', 'c-44'...
and then perform a query that like

```
select column_X from table_1 where ponum in (@ponum)
```

and then user click on a expression link which send the rows to another report to perform another action via a query. such as

```
update table_1 set column_A = '123' where ponum in (@ponum)
```

My problem is I can't send the parameter as a multiple values parameter. I added an expression for user to click and added the parameter in this window
[image: Parameter adding window]

I also tried

```
=join(Parameters!ponum.Value,", ")

="'"+join(Parameters!ponum.Value,"', '")+"'"
```

In Report_2, I set up the parameter as this
[image]

Unfortunately, the report it goes to only receive the first value or the query doesn't work and parameter being the problem.

Would like to hear any idea that might work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the parameter in the first report multi-value? or is it a single value string containing comma separated values? If the parameter in the first report is muti-valued then you can simply set that as the parameter of your second report, the second report's parameter must also be multi-valued. There will be no need to do any string manipulation or using JOIN(), just pass the whole parameter.

Comment: Yes the parameter in the first report is multi-value, I enter multi-value of string and the report automatically convert to comma separated with quotation around the values.

I did exactly what you suggested at first but the second report only receive the first value. That's also the reason I tried to use JOIN

Comment: Looking at your last screen sot, your parameter in report 2 is not multi-value, you need to check the "Allow multiple values" option. When parameters in both reports are multi-value you can pass the entire parameter so you would pass the parameter value as `[@myReport1Parameter]` in the Action property (this is equivalent to setting the value to `=Parameters!myReport1Parameter.Value`)

Comment: I got it working! SSRS automatically set the value to =Parameters!myReport1Parameter.Value(0)). That's why I was only getting the first row. You always help me Thanks Alan!